# Errors when trying to add an App or Page on any site collection SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, app, application-pages

I'm having this random issue. When trying to add an app or a page on any of my site collections i get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'App_Web_errorv15.master.9c9699a8.tism8wyx, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))

I checked the logs and I find the same error msg on there:

> 05/04/2017 12:14:31.38    w3wp.exe (0x0BDC)
>     0x1E14  SharePoint Foundation           General
>     ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception
>   System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load file or
>   assembly 'App_Web_errorv15.master.9c9699a8.rkml6usk, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could
>   not load file or assembly 'App_Web_errorv15.master.9c9699a8.rkml6usk,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'App_Web_errorv15.master.9c9699a8.rkml6usk,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. ... f670ee9d-19e0-70c4-ffb0-92253840f919

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: are you using any custom master page that deployed by VS?

Comment: No we're not a custom master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys - i was able to fix it by running the PSCONFIG and rebooting the web servers. Not sure exactly what caused this issue but PSCONFIG seemed to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx) for getting details of the failed assembly binds.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys - i was able to fix it by running the PSCONFIG and rebooting the web servers. Not sure exactly what caused this issue but PSCONFIG seemed to have fixed it.